# why and how pdf scrolling on browser causes brief blur

Tags: pdf, browser, microsoft-edge

Why and how does pdf scrolling cause brief blurs on revealed content? (Using Microsoft edge here)[Video example](https://i.gyazo.com/0ca0052062f48b9db1e58da82b208be6.mp4)

Answer (score -1):

I can reproduce the issue in latest version of Edge. There's no known workarounds at the moment other than using an alternative PDF reader.

AFAIK, the same issue has been reported and the Edge Product Group is evaluating possible ways to improve user experience. I suggest that you can also provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. Let's waiting for the improvement in Edge's future updates. Thanks for your understanding.